Wordpress Woocommerce Passwort Reset Loop
This question pops up from time to time, but in recent years, it seems to have stopped happening. All questions and answers to this problem are more than 4–6 years old.
Currently, I am experiencing the same issue. I have a hosted website with WordPress and WooCommerce. The problem in question is as follows: After clicking on the “Lost Password” link and filling out the email form, the user receives an email with the correct key and ID, but they are forwarded to the same entry point instead of the password reset form where they can enter their new password.
I know the link is correct because sometimes it works.
The link in the email looks like this:
https://<domain>/mein-konto/lost-password/?key=xOmnpbYj5XITPzOzVtG0&id=261

It forwards to this page:
https://<domain>/mein-konto/lost-password/?show-reset-form=true&action

If further information is needed, I can happily provide more. Just ask. There is no source code. I can only provide PHP files from the site and specific settings.
Here is a link to the WooCommerce Status Report: https://gist.github.com/mowi12/c596cb1869f4c12dcf52f9fa01a94dfd
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
I investigated a little further and found out that there is a cookie that is needed in order for the password reset functionality to work.
The problem is that this cookie is only created in firefox, but not in any other browser.
After manually adding this cookie in Chrome, the link worked, which supports my idea.
Does anyone know why this cookie is only created in Firefox and not in any other browser?
The cookie looks like this:
wp-resetpass-51768d40xxxxxxxxc0f1ee782
261%3A83xxxxxxxxxrC9NTiL

The first line is the name, the second line is the key.

The issue where the cookie is only created in Firefox and not in other browsers like Chrome could be due to the SameSite cookie attribute or privacy settings. Chrome and other browsers have stricter policies on cross-site cookies, which could prevent the cookie from being set correctly. Firefox may be more permissive.
To fix this:

Check the SameSite attribute of the cookie. Set it to SameSite=None with the Secure flag if needed.
Review the privacy settings in Chrome or other browsers, which may block third-party cookies.
Clear the cache and test the functionality again.


SameSite=None as well as the Secure flag are already set as you described. These are the default values for this cookie. I dont think that this is the issue. But thank you for the idea.
